# php login system with blowfish

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, blowfish

I am having problem logging in to my database using the blowfish method (the problem is that it doesnt detect the wrong password ).

```
<?php
         if(isset($_POST['signin'])){   

        global $connection;

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $safe_username = mysql_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
            $password = $_POST['password'];


        if (empty($username) or empty($password))
        {
            header("location: error.php");
        } else {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$safe_username}'";
        $result = mysql_query($connection, $query);
        if($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $set_password = $rows['password'];
            $input_password = crypt($password, $set_password);
        }

        if ($input_password == $set_password) {
        header("location: ../pages/profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page


        } else {
            header ("location: wrong-error.php");
        } 

    } 
    }

    }
?>
```

please help ;(

Comment: if you can't be bothered to explain HOW this code isn't working, why should we GUESS what the problem might be?

Comment: try to remove curly braces `username = '$safe_username'";`

Comment: @MarcB if i login with a wrong password or username or even empty forms it logs me in and i don't want that i want the code to detect if it's wrong and if it is go to error page and if not log me in hope you understood what i mean

Comment: @Alex surely using single quotes around the php variable will result in the string value '$safe_username' no?

Comment: @alex: that's perfectly legal PHP string syntax. the `{}` are not whatever the problem is.

Comment: @Marc B is '{$safe_username}' not going to result in the string literal value rather than expanding the variable?

Comment: no, because the string is enclosed with `"`. the `'` are for mysql, not php.

Comment: nobody's spotted the obvious

Comment: @Fred-ii- many did probably. I take it we're all tired from the same old :)

Comment: @N.B. Got that right. I'm just here to lend some "assistance" ;-) [Here for a good time, ♫ not a long time....](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myfV3hB-sKQ)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `PHP 5.5+`, you can take advantage of the new password functions:

- [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Those greatly streamline the process now. It is also backwards compatible with `crypt()` if you use the `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` algo in the function params.

While that may help, it may not solve your problem if it is a SQL one. Please do share any errors. You can get the last `mysql` error via the `mysql_error` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Also consider using a library for your SQL operations and/or updating to `mysqli`. 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

Comment: Good call to the MySQL error function. Rare to see that, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what mistakes have already been pointed out by others:

```
if($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $set_password = $rows['password'];
    $input_password = crypt($password, $set_password);
}

if ($input_password == $set_password) {
header("location: ../pages/profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
```

Imagine what happens here, if `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false` …? (F.e. because the query was syntactically incorrect, or just returned an empty result set.)

Neither `$set_password` nor `$input_password` will get initialized with any value at all, and then on the next `if` statement, they are both just undefined variables – and comparing the “values” of those two for equality will result in `true`.

---

First of all, go set your PHP error_reporting to a value that is suitable for development – then at least PHP gets a chance to tell you about mistake like this. (If you don’t know what this means, research it please.)

And then go read up on how sensible error handling is done, when you make database queries with PHP.

---

And btw., all of your Location headers are *wrong* as well – a `Location` header *requires* an absolute URL *by definition*.

Comment: it's unwise, but `location` headers do work with a relative url

Comment: @Martin: I’ve seen plenty of cases already where they didn’t. To be fair, most browsers handle them as expected, and clients other than browsers might not be that relevant in this instance here – but there is no good reason for doing something the _wrong_ way, when it can easily be done the _right_ way.

Comment: from PHP manual: `Most contemporary clients accept relative URIs as argument to » Location:, but some older clients require an absolute URI including the scheme, hostname and absolute path.` . While you are correct a absolute address *should* be given, a relative address is not actually *wrong*. Also what is more important is that a script should be terminated with a `die()` statement after the header to prevent further execution once the header is reached.

Comment: I agree with your point of view, about best methods, but the syntax used by OP is not actually *wrong*. -- such is PHP.....

Comment: There are two things that won't happen in OP's code. The escape function and the query. I'm surprised nobody spotted that.

Comment: TBH Fred, the code is a mess, and I'm resisting answering it as others have got it almost right, and I'm not good at answering parts as I'd have to fix *all* the issues that I see for my own satisfaction. So, I hope someone else writes a good enough answer that I won't need to. :-)

Comment: @Martin: I didn’t say it was wrong PHP syntax – but it is _wrong_ from an HTTP perspective.

Comment: @Martin *Aye*, ditto there.

Comment: All I'm saying in my comment, is that the wording `all of your Location headers are wrong`. as they're not wrong, just not how they should be. Likewise with the important fact of putting `die` after said headers. I do agree with your point of view 100% though, but I clarify the wording...

Comment: @Fred-ii-: _“I'm surprised nobody spotted that”_ – given the plentiful choice of errors and mistakes here, it’s hard to spot them at a glance. But proper error reporting would have spotted them _for_ the OP :-)

Answer (score 1):

An assessment:

```
<?php
         if(isset($_POST['signin'])){   

        global $connection;
```

Don't use globals. It's bad practise. If you need the connection value it is better to use an `include` statement which returns the `$connection` variable.

```
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $safe_username = mysql_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
            $password = $_POST['password'];


        if (empty($username) or empty($password))
        {
            header("location: error.php");
```

`headers` should always be followed immediately by an `exit`/`die` statement to stop the rest of the code being run before the script moves to focus on the new location.

Also, what is the point in setting the real_escape_string POST username value as a new value, are you intending to reuse the *unescaped* value?

```
        } else {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$safe_username}'";
```

Do not select `*` this is unwise and relatively costly on the MySQL, better to select the values you want, in this case you only appear to use the 'password' field. So `Select password FROM...`

Also good practise to add a `LIMIT 1` to the SQL as you will only ever be looking for one username.

```
        $result = mysql_query($connection, $query);
```

This line is the principle cause of your issue, you have a layout as if using mysqli but you are coding in standard mysql. Mysql is ***deprecated*** and should no longer be used, instead use MySQLi, which has the same layout as you have above, but is still maintained and has lots of security fixes and other advantages to MySQL. Please use it.

As it stands the line above will not execute and will return an error
or otherwise FALSE, so the line below will never execute to `TRUE`:

```
        if($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

This row *might* work (given the given values are valid) as an `if` but is more usually a `while` statement. Replace the If for a `While`.

```
            $set_password = $rows['password'];
            $input_password = crypt($password, $set_password);
```

Your crypt statement is wrong, the syntax of `crypt` is `crypt($txt, $salt)` but you have supplied a password value twice. This is non-sense. If you have PHP 5.3+ then you can use the built in password_ functions from PHP core.

see http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

```
        }

        if ($input_password == $set_password) {
```

These maybe equal but what you are comparing may also both be unset/NULL, your above crypt statement is nonsense so these will both give incorrect results. This is a primary cause for your issue.

Also in your issue is that if the `$_POST['password']` is empty then your first header is launched, but then because you did not `die` after your first header statment, the code continues to execute and then finds this header statement ( because `if(NULL == NULL)` === true ) and so this header supersedes the first header and this is why you're being logged in even if your details are empty.

```
        header("location: ../pages/profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
```

Again, add an `exit` here. Also better to use an absolute address such as `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/pages/profile.php"`.

```
        } else {
            header ("location: wrong-error.php");
        } 

    } 
    }

    }
?>
```

You also have two too many closing brackets in your code.

Also, use PHP error correctly as referenced by CBroe, these are wise words of his.

I repeat, use MySQLi. Error log with PHP error settings. Both of these details are highly accessible from Stack Overflow. Also really, really look into using PHP password functions rather than Crypt directly, because at the moment, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have weird logic here:

```
 if($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $set_password = $rows['password'];
    $input_password = crypt($password, $set_password); <-- This is weird
 }
 if ($input_password == $set_password) {
```

When you `crypt` 2nd parameter is **salt**. Salt should be some constant. But you just get it from the `$rows`.

If you can post your code where you do your `INSERT` to see which **salt** was used during the insert, you can change your line to something like:

```
 $input_password = crypt($password, $constant_salt_from_insert);
```

Comment: @AndrewB if `crypt` function was used instead of `password_hash` while insert, `password_verify` is useless I guess...

Comment: Sorry yeah I had realised after I posted